# Ruby - reference of self in the class method

Tags: ruby, class, methods

Went over this code on RubyMonk:

```
 class Item
   def initialize(item)
     @item = item
   end
   def show
     puts "The item name is: #{self}"
   end
   def to_s
     "#{@item}"
   end
 end

 Item.new("potion").show
```

The code passes but the use of the self variable is a bit ambiguous to me. You could've easily supplanted to_s with self in the show method and gotten the same results. Can somebody explain the difference between both interpolations and why/how self is used here?
Additionally, without the the method to_s, the code returns a proxy. What is the significance of defining the to_s here?

Comment: `to_s` is the standard Ruby method for converting an object to a string. By defining it in `class Item`, you've made it available in that class, so when you print the object with `#{self}` as a string, Ruby is smart enough to go for the `to_s` method. Without the `to_s` method, you just get an inspection of the object reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's true that, in the example you provided, you could have just written `"The item name is: #{@item}"`, that's not always the case.

As CDub points out, string interpolation implicitly calls `to_s`. If an object doesn't define a `to_s` method, Ruby returns an object reference in its place. In the example you gave us, writing `"The item name is: #{@item}"` only works because `String` implements `to_s`. If it didn't, or if you use `Item` to hold an object that doesn't implement `to_s`, you'll end up with the object's reference.

Now for the difference between using `self` and `@item` in your interpolation. `self` refers to the current object. When you interpolate `self`, you're calling the current object's `to_s` method. When you interpolate `@item`, you're calling `@item`'s `to_s` method. That's not a problem in this simple case, but let's look at something a little bit more complex. Say we have two classes, `Item` and `OtherItem` (creative names, I know).

```
 class Item
   def initialize(item)
     @item = item
   end
   def show
     puts "The item name is: #{self}"
   end
   def to_s
     "I'm a chunky monkey!"
   end
 end

  class OtherItem
   def initialize(item)
     @otherItem = item
   end
   def to_s
     "#{@otherItem}"
   end
 end
```

In this scenario, `Item`'s `show` method uses `self`, so if we were to write:

```
Item.new(OtherItem.new("potion")).show
```

Ruby would call `Item.show`, which, in turn, would call `self.to_s`. Since `self` in that context is an `Item`, our output would be:

```
"The item name is: I'm a chunky monkey!"
```

If, however, we redefined `Item.show` like this:

```
def show
  puts "The item name is: #{@item}"
end
```

And tried calling `Item.new(OtherItem.new("potion")).show` again, `Item.show` would call `@item.to_s`, and fill that in instead, so we'd get:

```
"The item name is: potion"
```

Answer (score 3):

String interpolation implicitly calls the `to_s` method on an object.  So, when you define the `to_s` method on `Item`, you are *explicitly* telling that object how to represent itself with respect to a string.  `self` is used in this case because there is an implicit call to `to_s` within the interpolation of the `Item` object.  Defining `to_s` *explicitly* tells `Item` how to render itself within a string.

For some additional details, check out [this excellent post on explicit vs. implicit conversion methods.](http://codeloveandboards.com/blog/2014/03/18/explicit-vs-implicit-conversion-methods/)